# Want to disable looping in lottie animation

Tags: android, react-native, lottie, bodymovin

I was wondering how I can run a Lottie animation only once since it is looping by default.
Here is a link to the code I am trying to modify: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/lottie.html

Comment: Just pass `loop={false}`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `loop` prop to set looping behavior of the component. More info about the properties you can use with lottie can be found [here](http://airbnb.io/lottie/react-native/props.html).

```
 // A boolean flag indicating whether or not the animation should loop.
 loop: boolean = false,
```

Answer (score 3):

In flutter , just do `repeat:false` after asset

Like this :

```
Lottie.asset('assets/lottie.json',repeat: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

In java disable looping in lottie animation like this maybe help this:

First, declare LottieAnimationView : `LottieAnimationView myAnim;`

Then find with ID: `myAnim = v.findViewById(R.id.upload_anim);` // v is view here, i use it because i work in fragment.

Now you can change looping option with boolean: `myAnim.loop(false);`